# Can accomplices in the same crime have contact before trial/during jail time?

Tags: united-kingdom, manslaughter

This is just pure curiosity. Under UK law can two people who are charged with the same crime (that they supposedly committed together) have contact with each other?

Fictional case: a woman and her live-in boyfriend were charged with the death of the woman's toddler. Manslaughter by gross negligence. She will subsequently be sentenced to several years in prison, he will get much less jail time.
She was held in remand, he was released on bail.

1. Would they have been allowed contact before trial, while he was free and she in prison? (visitations or calls/letters)
2. Would they have been allowed contact while both were serving their prison terms? (eg calls/letters)
3. When the boyfriend was released and the woman still in prison, would he have been allowed to visit her?

Comment: pre-trial this depends on many factors, including the likelyhood they might exchange case relevant information.